# How to Convert .flv file to .mp4 in Node JS

Tags: node.js

This not working file size will be 0B

```
var src = path.join('/live/streams', streamName + '.flv');
var destDir = path.join('/new/streams', streamName + '.mp4');
 let writeStream =  fs.createWriteStream(destDir);
ffmpeg(src).format('mp4').pipe(writeStream, {end: true});
```

Comment: This totally depends on what package you're using for ffmpeg. `await fs.createWriteStream(destDir)` doesn't make sense, it isn't a promise.

Comment: use https://www.npmjs.com/package/handbrake-js package